# How to dynamically set the width of a devexpress control from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I have four devexpress dropdownbox controls displayed using an HTML table/tr/td. Depending upon who logged in, either all four or only three of the controls have to be displayed. I want the controls to occupy the entire width of the page whether four or three controls are displayed. Please let me know how could do this. I believe one way is create an hidden aspx control to set the loggedin value from the code behind. And then read this value to set the class property of the td or the devexpress control to set the width. Wondering whether there is an easier way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
        <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td id="td1" runat="server">
                <dx:ASPxDropDownEdit runat="server" Width="100%">
                </dx:ASPxDropDownEdit>
            </td>
            <td id="td2" runat="server">
                <dx:ASPxDropDownEdit runat="server" Width="100%">
                </dx:ASPxDropDownEdit>
            </td>
            <td id="td3" runat="server">
                <dx:ASPxDropDownEdit runat="server" Width="100%">
                </dx:ASPxDropDownEdit>
            </td>
            <td id="td4" runat="server">
                <dx:ASPxDropDownEdit runat="server" Width="100%">
                </dx:ASPxDropDownEdit>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Code-behind:

```
if(true) //your condition
   td1.Visible = false;
```